# How to disable creation of new rows in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is about a .NET Windows Forms application written in C#. I have a `DataGridView` which is connected to a database. It displays the contents of a selected table.

Now if there are 4 rows in that table, it will display 4 rows. After this I am able to enter the 5<sup>th</sup> row in the datagrid view. It should be avoided. Now I have to disable creation of a new row. How can I do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Simply set the [`DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) property to `false`.

Answer (score 10):

Set

```
dataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false
```

Answer (score 2):

In XAML, set the property `CanUserAddRows` to false. For example see the following code

```
 <DataGrid   CanUserAddRows="False">

 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in WPF, but I don't think it works in Windows Forms. It helped me out tho in WPF

Answer (score -6):

Do this:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = (set the original source back)
```