# How to hide(or remove) the last empty row?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

A blank line is printed as if you had checked it in yellow in Gridview.
I changed all the properties of Gridview but it did not disappear.
How can I remove that empty row?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEzJ8.png)

```
class Class1
{
    private List<MemberModel> sourceList;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetGridControlData(this.sourceList);

        this.gridView.Columns.Clear();

        this.gridView.Columns.Add(GetGridColumn("idColumn"     , "ID"     , "아이디"     , true));
        this.gridView.Columns.Add(GetGridColumn("nameColumn"   , "Name"   , "이름"       , true));

    }

    private GridColumn GetGridColumn(string name, string fieldName, string caption, bool visible)
    { 
        GridColumn column = new GridColumn();

        column.Name      = name;
        column.FieldName = fieldName;
        column.Caption   = caption;
        column.Visible   = visible;

        return column;
    }

    private void SetGridControlData(List<MemberModel> sourceList)
    {
        this.gridControl.DataSource = sourceList;

        this.gridControl.RefreshDataSource();
    }
}

public class MemberModel
{
    public string ID{ get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666238/how-to-disable-creation-of-new-rows-in-a-datagridview

Comment: @Luchspeter I already saw that post. but It's not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DevExpress grid view, you can hide the new item row by setting `NewItemRowPosition` to `NewItemRowPosition.None` [as described here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridOptionsView.NewItemRowPosition.property). For example,

`this.gridView.GridOptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = NewItemRowPosition.None;`